# how can i auto-generate sets of 3 colors (border, fill & text) that go together

Tags: color-scheme, color-palette

I am trying to automatically generate a bunch of images all
containing a border, a fill and a text label within.

I am using a script to generate a svg file that I subsequently rasterize using [batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html)

I'm looking for either

- an algorithm to generate distinct color sets that go together
- or a pre-canned set of colors that someone has put together

Pointers appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across sassafras that provides a good building block

https://github.com/teejayvanslyke/sassafras

and it references

http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm

to help with color theory

Answer (score 0):

I have used this online colour scheme generator for "quick fixes".

http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html